# Bash script that handles multiple user inputs of python program

Tags: python, bash

I have a python program that prompts for user input (via CLI) multiple times.

Just for example, let's say I have a `test.py` file that prompts for `input1`, and then, some time after, `input2`:

```
...
...
input1 = input("Enter input 1")
...
...
input2 = input("Enter input 2")
...
...
```

How do I go about writing a bash script that runs this program, waits for and then gives the argument for `input1`, and then waits again for `input2` and gives its argument?

If you can point me in the right direction it would be great; everything I found online was about multiple inputs for the actual bash script, or about multiple arguments (as a single input). I am not experienced with bash scripting as well, so I apologize in advance if my lack of experience was the reason why I couldn't find the right resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just redirect stdin to the data you want. In the shell script, you can use `<<` to put the data in the script itself. When bash sees `<< EOF` it pushes everything in the script up to the next "EOF" to the called program's stdin.

test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
input1 = input("Enter input 1")
input2 = input("Enter input 2")
print("Got", input1, input2)
```

test.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
./test.py <<EOF
I am input 1
I am input 2
EOF
```

This is called a [*Here Document*](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) and you can use any word in place of `EOF`.

Comment: I can't upvote (new account restrictions), but thank you so much!